# Modify some files to add the file name

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have a bunch of text (hundreds of txt) inside a directory. Each of them has a unique filename. I want to insert filename of each file into the first line of respective files. How can I do that using bash script?

Comment: See [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-prepend-text-lines-to-file/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard approach is to use temporary files, but you can change files in place if you enclose `cat` in `$()` parenthesis:

```
for file in *.txt; do echo "$file"$'\n'"$(cat -- "$file")" > "$file"; done
```

Comment: if file name has a space in it then??

Comment: @KasiyA Just put double quotes everywhere required.

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in *; do
 (echo "$file"; cat -- "$file") > "$file.new"
 mv -- "$file.new" "$file"
done
```

This loops over all files
echoes each filename and
appends the contents of the file
then all placing it into a new file
with the additional suffix of `.new`.

You create a new file for each existing one,
so you must rename the files afterwards.

You can place the results into a new directory
and then remove the old one:

```
mkdir new
for file in *; do
 (echo "$file"; cat "$file") > "new/$file"
done
```

You can also use sed with option `-i`
to do in-place editing of the files.
Perl also allows this.  It all depends
on what other tools you have available. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the standard text editor:

```
for f in *; do printf '%s\n' 1i "$f" . w q | ed "$f"; done
```